# Using hardhat impersonate fund with hardhat reset fork: sender doesn't have enough funds

Tags: hardhat

I'm using hardhat impersonate funds using this function:

```
const { network, ethers } = require("hardhat");
const hre = require("hardhat")

const fundErc20 = async (contract, sender, recepient, amount, decimals) => {
  const FUND_AMOUNT = ethers.utils.parseUnits(amount, decimals);
  // fund erc20 token to the contract
  const whale = await ethers.getSigner(sender);

  const contractSigner = contract.connect(whale);
  console.log("Error is here") //Error is here
  await contractSigner.transfer(recepient, FUND_AMOUNT);
  
};

const impersonateFundErc20 = async (
  contract,
  sender,
  recepient,
  amount,
  decimals
) => {
  
  await network.provider.request({
    method: "hardhat_impersonateAccount",
    params: [sender],
  });

  // fund baseToken to the contract
  await fundErc20(contract, sender, recepient, amount, decimals);
  
  await network.provider.request({
    method: "hardhat_stopImpersonatingAccount",
    params: [sender],
  });
};

module.exports = {
  impersonateFundErc20: impersonateFundErc20,
};
```

It works ok, but I'm sending transactions inside a for loop cycle and today I tried to reset fork after each loop:

```
for (let g of arr){
    
    await Borrow(g,found) 
    await hre.network.provider.send("hardhat_reset")
  }

async function Borrow(c,found){

const whale_balance = await provider.getBalance(whale);
expect(whale_balance).not.equal("0");
console.log('Whale Balance',whale_balance);

const SwapExamples = await ethers.getContractFactory("FlashLoanRecipient")
swapExamples = await SwapExamples.deploy()
await swapExamples.deployed()
console.log("deployed")
```

As long as I come to this point, I'm getting an error:

1. If I use waffle : `AssertionError: Expected "0" NOT to be equal 0`
2. If I use `const provider = new ethers.providers.JsonRpcProvider` :
   `InvalidInputError: sender doesn't have enough funds to send tx. The max upfront cost is: 55466042452206 and the sender's account only has: 0`

> ```
> await impersonateFundErc20(
>       tokenBase,
>       whale,
>       swapExamples.address,
>       initialFundingHuman,
>       decimalsId1
>     );
> ```

First loop works fine but then I'm getting errors right inside impersonateFundErc20 function.
As I understand hardhat resets the fork and that's why it doesn't see any money of the whale.

Is it possible in theory to use both this functions together? I tried to change location of reset function and it doesn't help.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm reading right (not guaranteed), the problem isn't related to the resets. (As a side point, I am a bit curious why you're resetting, but that might be a side thing.) Let's look at the error message you're getting from the path with the provider:

```
InvalidInputError: sender doesn't have enough funds to send tx. The max upfront cost is: 55466042452206 and the sender's account only has: 0
```

This implies that a signer is sending a tx, but doesn't have the ether to cover gas. In the script, it looks like this is happening right by a deployment - it seems like the deployer (looks like it's `accounts[0]` since no signer is specified) doesn't have enough ether to cover the deployment. This may even be due to the fact that the fork was reset - it may have taken away any prefunded ether. Either way, if this is the case, there's good news; Hardhat also provides a method for arbitrarily funding an account with ether - [`hardhat_setBalance`](https://hardhat.org/hardhat-network/docs/reference#hardhat_setbalance). If you call that (after the reset, or the reset will undo it), you should be able to fund the account with enough ether for deployment.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks for your help. If I have several transactions to make, it takes more that 1 block time to check them all with for loop. So the last transactions take place not in current block but in the previous block (If I understand forking right). And also in the end I'm transfering funds to my wallet and with each loop it accumulates funds, but I need it to be fresh with 0 funds.

Comment: I tried setBalance. But even without it contract is deploying without problems. I have an error right befor transfering funds from whale to my contract address. Looks like the whole world disappears after resetting and hardhat doesn't see funds of this whale.

Comment: I've just decided to check how fork works with blocks. Await provider.getBlockNumber() shows that every loop I'm in the new current block. Only using waffle.provider returns blocks from the future(I don't know how it happens tbh)) So thanks for your question why do I need it? I've learned smth new about forking in Hardhat.